# Constrain a multivariate function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, terminology

If given a function $F(x,y)$ of two separate and independent variables $x$ and $y$, would it be possible to define a relation between the two variables that is only true for *certain combinations* of values, without changing their independence.

For example,

I define that for certain pairs of values that

$x=y$

and define a function $F_r(x,y)$  on the domain A containing tuples $(a_0,a_0)$ for any real number $a_0$

As we've limited the domain of $F_r$ even though it should be a multivariate function, and it takes two arguments it's domain is limited so that it can't take any two choices of $x$ or $y$, can this be described as a multivariate function anymore?

We also see that $F_r$ is not really continuous in all directions on its domain $A$ and we find that we cannot define the partial derivatives, this is much like a function where we explicitly define a relation for all $x$ and $y$ and define $F(x,y)$
and it makes sense in this case, for some combination $x,y$ the relation

$F(x,y)=F_r(x,y)=g(x)=g(y)$

should hold in this case.

Is it acceptable for two independent variables to introduce a constraint like this which is true only for when they have values such that they follow this relation?
Would I say that $x$ and $y$ are dependent (in that context) when we are only interested in the particular set of tuples $(x,y) ∈ A$ or that they simply *act* as dependent if we were to only consider relationships that are true in the case that the values of $x$ and $y$ fall under this given relation, but that they are independent in general?

Comment: I see it as a surface in 3 dimensions and then your case is an additional constraint such that we consider only the surface above the strait line which goes through x and y. So now you would have a line curve ultimately determined buy the original 3 d surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above Question is a continuation of a thread started by the OP in their [previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4393159/21813). Here is the original discussion *migrated* over (to tidy up the duplication):

> When dealing with a function $F(x,y)$, I wish to analyze when its
> arguments are equal.
>
> Given a function $F(x,y)=xy,$ both $x,y$ are 'varying' in this case.
> $F(x,y)$ cannot be expressed as a single variable function $g$ (which
> takes one argument) application to any one variable (they are
> 'independent').
>
> When we define $x=y$ for $F(x,y),$ we run into a slightly confusing
> statement, if for $x$ or $y$ we want to analyze them for differing
> values, then based on this relationship (in this context) they seem to
> be not independent anymore.

The domain of the given function $F$ is the plane $\mathbb R^2;$ as such, its inputs $x$ and $y$ are independent of each other.

When the *dependency* $x=y$ is imposed as a constraint, a new function $F_r$ (called the restriction of $F$) is created. The inputs of $F_r$ mutually depend on each other, so its domain is a proper subset of $\mathbb R^2.$

To be clear:

1. $F$ has domain $\mathbb R^2$ and rule $F(x,y)=xy$
2. $F_r$ has domain $\{(x,x)\vert x\in\mathbb R\}$ (a line in $\mathbb R^2$) and rule
   $F_r(x,y)=xy$
3. $g$ has domain $\mathbb R$ and rule $g(x)=x^2.$