# Verifying Difference between a variable and a parameter

Tags: definition

I'm not quite sure of the formal difference between a variable and a parameter.  The way I explain a parameter is that while its input value differs from case to case, the concept is always the same.  Examples include B for base, h for height, etc.  A variable is a symbol whose value and the concept it stands for both differ from problem to problem/case to case.  For example, x has both different values and different things it represents.  Is this correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: You are mostly correct in your understanding. a parameter is a constant that is used to describe the behavior of a function or equation, and its value remains constant. a variable is a symbol that represents a value that changes as the input to a function or equation changes.

For example, is the equation $y=mx+b$, where $m$ and $b$ are parameters and $x$ is a variable, the slope $m$ and the y-intercept $b$ are fixed values that determine the the line. the value of the line at any point $x$ changes depending on the value of $x$.

Comment: I addressed your query in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4393634/21813) and in the links within it.

Comment: knight5478 - thanks!  I'm assuming it works the same way for computer science?