# Difference between arbitrary constant and free variable

Tags: logic, soft-question, first-order-logic

Take the following mathematical sentence $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$, before I learnt about first-order-logic I would say, $x$ is a variable and $a,b,c$ are all arbitrary constants. Now after learning about logic I would write down something like $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$, where $x$ is a bound variable and $a,b,c$ are free variables. Do these two interpretations agree with each other, or is one wrong?

Comment: They agree: an arbitrary constants acts as a free variable.

Comment: Thank you so much, being able to make links between formal logic and everyday maths is making me a much better mathematician.

Comment: The key issue is "arbitrary" that means a name with no specific meaning. The difference is formal: in math logic you cannot quantify it.

Comment: Just different interpretations for same thing, both are just as valid.

Comment: *"$a,b,c$ are arbitrary constants. $a,b,c$ are free variables. Do these two interpretations agree with each other?"* $\quad$  [Variously calling](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4393634/21813) the *placeholder* $\text‘b\text’$ a(n **arbitrary**) **constant**, a (**free**) **variable**, and a **parameter** —depending on the context, framing and emphasis—is not a contradiction in terms.

Comment: All good there, thanks ryang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments you have gotten so far are inaccurate. In your first sentence "arbitrary constant" does not have a proper meaning, and is ambiguous or incorrect depending on exactly how you interpreted it. In the first place, it is not even really a "mathematical sentence" as it is missing its context. In the typical contexts, $a,b,c$ are the same for every $x$, and any proper mathematical writing would make that clear such as in:

1. [In a context where $f : ℝ→ℝ$ has already been defined, we may make deductions until..] There are $a,b,c∈ℝ$ such that $f(x) = a·x^2+b·x+c$ for every $x∈ℝ$. Symbolically, $∃a,b,c{∈}ℝ\ ∀x{∈}ℝ\ ( \ f(x) = a·x^2+b·x+c \ )$.
2. [In a context where $a,b,c∈ℝ$ have already been defined..] Let $f : ℝ→ℝ$ such that $f(x) = a·x^2+b·x+c$ for each $x∈ℝ$. Symbolically, [we pick a fresh variable $f$ and then can write down..] $∀x{∈}ℝ\ ( \ f(x) = a·x^2+b·x+c \ )$.

Note that in both cases there is nothing arbitrary about $a,b,c$. In the first case, we prove that there is some **specific** combination of $a,b,c$ such that $∀x{∈}ℝ\ ( \ f(x) = a·x^2+b·x+c \ )$, and it may be that there is only one. In the second case, $a,b,c$ have been defined earlier, and may be **specific** too.